# how to print the text before the first index number?

Tags: python, html

this is the code I have:

```
>>> text= """ this is an example Item&nbsp;2 text text <B>Item&nbsp;2. example"""
>>> a=re.search ('(?<=<B>)Item&nbsp;2\.',text)
>>> b = a.span()
>>> print (b)
(45, 57)
>>>
```

how can I print all the text that comes before the first index number (before 45)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `text[:start]`:

```
In [76]: import re

In [77]: text = """ this is an example Item&nbsp;2 text text <B>Item&nbsp;2. example"""

In [78]: a = re.search ('(?<=<B>)Item&nbsp;2\.',text)

In [79]: start, end = a.span()

In [80]: text[:start]
Out[80]: ' this is an example Item&nbsp;2 text text <B>'
```

The match object `a` also knows the value of `text`; it is accessible through its `string` attribute:

```
In [91]: a.string[:start]
Out[91]: ' this is an example Item&nbsp;2 text text <B>'
```